# Rotate content around a central pivot in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So Im a graphic desinger and I've been asked to develop a concept for a client's new site. Its a micro-site with limited amounts of content. The idea I have come up with is to place all the sections of the site on divs and then rotate them like a wheel when a user clicks a menu link. What I need to find out is this: Is it possible to rotate entire divs containing normal content around a central pivot point using html5? The rotation needs to be animated the content contained in each rotated div needs to rotate in unison with its container div. If it is possible, how?

[image]

I've googled it and found examples of rotating stuff with CSS3 and I've seen html5 transformations but Im not sure I have seen anything this sophisticated before and I can't find any examples to work off. So Im a little concerned its not actually possible for some reason. Im also open to using something like javascript to make this happen.

Comment: Check out the examples here - http://www.webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/jasssonpet/nzK7E/embedded/result/):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">First</div>
    <div class="second">Second</div>
    <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform: rotate(0);
    position: relative;
}

.container>div {
    position: absolute;
}

.container.second {
    transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.container.third {
    transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.container .first {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.container .second {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
}
```

You can add some simple js to change the container current class.

Comment: So with something like this will all of the content contained each container div rotate as well?

Comment: Yes. The whole element will rotate.